# PayPal PHP SDK Refund Not Giving Parent_Payment

Tags: php, android, paypal

When working with the APK I am trying to use webhooks to receive refund information so that I can cancel out licenses if the user decides to reverse/refund after purchase.

When sending the refund webhook through the webhook simulator it sends me the refund ID which I can use to get the parent_payment of the Payment by using Refund::get($refundId, $api). The problem that I am having is that when I actually send a payment (through the paypal sandbox) and I go to the sandbox account and manually issue a refund, it sends me the webhook, but when I try and get the parent_payment ID it is blank and doesn't seem to be sent.

Comment: [Someone else had the same issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676798/get-details-parent-payment-of-a-refund) - it looks like if the payment is refunded manually the parent data is missing.

Comment: Interesting, alright thank you for the info. Im going to look more into this.